# Is suckback possible after removing stopper?

Tags: home-experiment

I am making hydrogen gas to fill a balloon. I will run the gas to a washing bottle with $\ce{NaOH}$ and then connect the balloon. I was wondering what would happen if I removed the stopper of my main reaction flask (e.g. to change wasted reagents) when the balloon is already half inflated.

1. Would $\ce{NaOH}$ get sucked out of the washing bottle somehow?
2. Would gas that's already in the balloon come out? Or the washing solution would prevent it?

[image: Scheme]

Comment: What are you mixing with NaOH to give you hydrogen gas? This wouldn't be the most common way of generating small amounts of hydrogen in the lab

Comment: I am mixing HCl with aluminium and bubbling the gas through NaOH.

Comment: A picture (or drawing) of your apparatus would be worth a thousand words.

Comment: @airhuff I have made the edit.

Comment: Well, yes, now the suckback looks quite possible.

Comment: What if I clamp the balloon and then remove the stopper?

Comment: It looks like you'd be pretty safe to clamp the balloon then remove the stopper. You probably know this, but absolutely wear safety goggles.